# How to iterate on a list of object but in specific field Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, iteration, dto

Lets say that i have a list of AccountDto (getContats() -> List)that each has a column accountId

```
List<Int> list = accountsDao.getContactIds()
```

and i have a list of MessageDto, where messageDto has a field 'fromAccountId'.
I want to loop through the messageList and find what new fromAccountId i have that dont exist in my DB.

```
getAccounts().value?.let {
            for ((every accountId from it.accountDto) in --(every fromAccountId in newMessages.list)--) {
                if (it.contains(newFromAccountId))
                    println("fount $newFromAccountId")
            }
        }
```

Is there an elegant way to do that in Kotlin...?

Comment: `new fromAccountId i have that dont exist in my DB` do you mean `!contains`?`if 
 (!it.contains(newFromAccountId))`

Comment: I think i have to edit the question....

Comment: If you want to iterate over a field of list object, convert the list to the field-list: `objectList.map { it.field }.forEach { /*print*/ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using nested `loops` which is not a very good idea, since time complexity of this operation is `O(n^2)`, performace will degrade very fast as the size of your `lists` increase.

Better approach on the expense of some extra memory would be to first create a `set` of all the accountId's from your `Database`, and then `iterate` over the `messageList` and for every `accoutId` check if the `set` contains this `accountId`.

```
// Store all the accountId's in a Set so that lookup is fast
var accountIds = getAccounts().map{it.accountId}.toSet()
// Iterate over the messageList and find the Id's that are not in Set
messageList.asSequence()
           .filter { !accountIds.contains(it.fromAccountId) }
           .forEach { println("fount $it") }
```

Comment: Excellent solution ;)